# F# 6 .NET tasks - how to use

Tags: f#

F# 6 [introduced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/whats-new/fsharp-6#task-) support for .NET tasks.

This snippet is shared everywhere - but what's the right way to call and use the result of the task (to e.g. `printf` it)?

```ml
let readFilesTask (path1, path2) =
   task {
        let! bytes1 = File.ReadAllBytesAsync(path1)
        let! bytes2 = File.ReadAllBytesAsync(path2)
        return Array.append bytes1 bytes2
   }
```

One option that works is:

```ml
let result = readFilesTask ("filaA", "fileB")
printf $"%A{result.Result}"
```

But is this the intended way of use?

Comment: In most cases you're going to be using a library or framework that expects to be passed a `Task<'T>` and you'll just interop with that. That's the primary use case and where async has always felt sort of annoying to use.

Comment: Yes, that was clear to me. My question was about how to access the result of the `Task<'T>` later on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few ways to work with tasks. What is the "intended" way will depend on what you are trying to achieve.

Also note that for many applications, `async` is only marginally slower but much easier to work with because it is "cold".

You can consume a task in another task using `let!` and `do!`:

```ml
task {
  let! x = someOtherTask ()
  do! andAnotherTask ()
  return x
}
```

You can start a task and not wait on the result (fire and forget):

```ml
let foo () = 
  task {
    printfn "Done."
  }

foo () |> ignore // tasks are "hot" unlike asyncs
```

You can turn a task into an `Async<'t>` using `Async.AwaitTask`:

```ml
async {
  do! 
    task {
      printfn "Done."
    }
    |> Async.AwaitTask
}
```

You can block the current thread until a task is complete:

```ml
let foo () = 
  task {
    printfn "Done."
  }

let t = foo ()
t.Result
```

I expect that most real applications will have lots of `do!` and `let!` statements, but only a few `.Result` calls in order to avoid blocking.